# what are the cflags of this microarchitecture?

Tags: command-line, hardware, c, architecture

I'm looking the cflags for the turion X2 M500 processor

I'm doing

```
grep -m1 -A3 "vendor_id" /proc/cpuinfo
```

and the output is:

```
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 16
model       : 6
model name  : AMD Turion(tm) II Dual-Core Mobile M500
```

Comment: "IM" is Instant Messaging; "I'm" is an abbreviation for "I am"

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Compiling with no `CFLAGS` set should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: Trying to optimize or take the best use of the microprocessor

Comment: @kusalananda thats right thankfully compiling with no CFLAGS work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your build environment is on the turion x2 machine:

- Step 1:  Assuming GNU gcc/g++, -mtune=native -march=native will build code optimized for the machine on which the compiler is run. I don't know how to tell the compiler to dump the chosen flags, but

If you want to cross-compile, you'll need to examine the capability flags for your processor:

- Step 1:  On your turion x2 machine:  cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep ^flags | sort -u
- Step 2:  Find the documentation for the -march directive and examine the possible cpu families for which directives exist.  For AMD cpus (I have a Turion x2 L310 notebook, but, sadly it's running Windows 10), look at the k8 or k8-sse targets.  According to the documentation for the 4.5.3 GNU compiler, those have the following characteristics:

  - k8, opteron, athlon64:  AMD K8 core based CPUs with x86-64 instruction set support. (This supersets MMX, SSE, SSE2, 3DNow!, enhanced 3DNow! and 64-bit instruction set extensions.)
  - k8-sse3, opteron-sse3, athlon64-sse3:  Improved versions of k8, opteron and athlon64 with SSE3 instruction set support.

To find out what architectures your compiler really supports, do this command (I'm assuming c++ is the target language):

```
g++ --help=target
```

Hopefully that's helpful.